# How to automate pushing of code from local repository to remote bitbucket repository?

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, bitbucket

We have job that automatically generates a java code and pushes to a local repository in linux.

I need to find a solution on how to push the newly created java code from local repo to bitbucket repo automatically.

Each time the java code is generated, it will be with different folder name.

Comment: it's can be done with something watching the folder. but why use different folder every time? Also, isn't the origin code (instead of generated code) should be commit in instead?

Comment: The code is generated automatically with the build number which will be the name of the folder. I need to automatically push the code to bitbucket or to trigger Jenkins job as and when a new folder is created in local repo.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your situation more, but basically if you
 `(optionally move/replace file)` `git add` then `git push` would be all right.

Comment: Okay let me explain clearly, Consider there is a local repository in linux under path /opt/repo. And i have 3 folders A, B, and C under my local repo. Now, when i add a folder D, it should automatically get committed into a new bitbucket repository or in a new branch of existing repository. Otherwise it has to automatically trigger build in jenkins when it detects a new folder in the local repo. Is there any way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: isn't `git add . && git commit <some param> && git push <some param> ` work?

Comment: git commands can be used for pushing the code to remote repo. My question is how to monitor a filesystem continuously to check if a new folder is added and if added how to push it automatically

Answer (score 0):

May it help you if you use branches?
You could create branches automatically and push them into bitbucket.

Comment: How can i automatically push to Bitbucket when a new folder is created in local repo?

Comment: If your jobs succeeds why u don´t create a new one that will run after this job and pushes to bitbucket?